# SSIS Package file in Notepad (.dtsx xml version)

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, msbi

I have a huge list of SSIS package, I wanted to know if any of the packages use the default path for the `bufferTempStoragePath` parameter. To do this quickly, I wanted to make a notepad search with this parameter and that's where I discovered that this parameter is not present in all xml versions .

Does anyone know if the package xml structure is similar? Otherwise, for this parameter appears on packages and others not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bufferTempStoragePath` has been an option back to the 2005 version of SSIS through to current (2017) version.

However, it is an attribute of a Data Flow Task. If the package has no Data Flow Tasks, you won't have any hits in your search. If you have 3 DFTs within a single package, you will have three property hits in your searching.

I was able to use the command prompt to reasonably identify packages that did/didn't have it set (or present)

```
type *.dtsx | find "bufferTempStoragePath"
```

`type` will list the contents of a file 
`|` pipes the results of the preceding command (type) into the next process
`find` performs a case sensitive text search

The results of that look like

```
dba_178090.dtsx


        <pipeline BLOBTempStoragePath="" bufferTempStoragePath="" name="pipelineXml" version="1">

Package1.dtsx



Package2.dtsx



Package3.dtsx


      bufferTempStoragePath="C:\tmp"
      bufferTempStoragePath="C:\src"
      bufferTempStoragePath="V:\"

RecordKeyTyping.dtsx


        <pipeline BLOBTempStoragePath="" bufferTempStoragePath="" name="pipelineXml" version="1">

so_43721322.dtsx



so_45063165.dtsx


        <pipeline BLOBTempStoragePath="" bufferTempStoragePath="" name="pipelineXml" version="1">

so_49262851.dtsx
```

I tried to get an explicit find for `bufferTempStoragePath=""` to work but there's something eating it when I pass it through the pipe [Escaping Double Quotes in Batch Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562038/181965)

Oh, and as I look at the parameters for find, I see that I can just search directly from it with `find "bufferTempStoragePath=""" .\*.dtsx` but I still can't get it to just find instances where the property is the empty string but the results are more concise

```
---------- .\DBA_178090.DTSX
        <pipeline BLOBTempStoragePath="" bufferTempStoragePath="" name="pipelineXml" version="1">

---------- .\PACKAGE1.DTSX

---------- .\PACKAGE2.DTSX

---------- .\PACKAGE3.DTSX
          bufferTempStoragePath="C:\tmp"
          bufferTempStoragePath="C:\src"
          bufferTempStoragePath="V:\"

---------- .\RECORDKEYTYPING.DTSX
        <pipeline BLOBTempStoragePath="" bufferTempStoragePath="" name="pipelineXml" version="1">

---------- .\SO_43721322.DTSX

---------- .\SO_45063165.DTSX
        <pipeline BLOBTempStoragePath="" bufferTempStoragePath="" name="pipelineXml" version="1">

---------- .\SO_49262851.DTSX
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,

Just a note, I have packages that use DFTs and we don't find this parameter bufferTempStoragePath  in the xml version of these packages.