# Escaping double quotes in sed for Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, sed

I was trying to write the following into a file using sed, in a Windows **.bat** file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Test|AnyCPU'">
```

I came across a problem when doing this, and that problem is that, in Windows, double quoting escaping is up to the program's implementation, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31413730/8966471). So writing the sequence into a text file was a real headache on sed for Windows.

Edit: Note that this question is NOT about how to escape double quotes in **batch**, but how to escape double quotes in **sed for Windows**, so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562038/escaping-double-quotes-in-batch-script) does not resolve the question.

For anyone wondering how to resolve this, see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

So let's see how I solved this. This is the test batch file and I'll explain its meaning below:

```
SET ConfigurationName="Test"
sed "1 a  <PropertyGroup Condition=\""'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'" == "'%ConfigurationName%|AnyCPU'\"">" "C:\Users\x\outputfile.txt" -i
```

In Windows' **sed**, the escaping of double quotes is done using `\"`.
Usually, at least in the Visual Studio Code's terminal, I could simply write the arguments for **sed** with single quotes, but I cannot do the same in a **.bat** file. This means that I need to escape the double quotes.

As you can see, the sequence `\""` is needed in order to escape the " character, and then keep writing in the file. If you don't, then $ is interpreted as a new command and Windows won't recognize it.

Another thing to mention is that `<` and `>` characters do not need to be escaped if written inside double quotes in sed.