# Schedule PowerShell commands

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I want to use the follwing powershell commands to automatically record a stream with vlc:

```
$rd = get-date -format "yyyyMMdd"
C:\"Program Files"\VideoLan\vlc\vlc.exe https://someurl/playlist.m3u --sout "#file{dst=C:\users\me\desktop\$rd.mp3}" --run-time=15 vlc://quit
```

That does work well if I save it as a .ps1 script and execute it with "Right Click > Run with PowerShell".

It also works if I paste those commands to the powershell and execute them in one line, like this:

```
$rd = get-date -format "yyyyMMdd"; C:\"Program Files"\VideoLan\vlc\vlc.exe https://someurl/playlist.m3u --sout "#file{dst=C:\users\me\desktop\$rd.mp3}" --run-time=15 vlc://quit
```

It even works if I execute this from within the Windows Terminal:

```
powershell -command {$rd = get-date -format "yyyyMMdd"; C:\"Program Files"\VideoLan\vlc\vlc.exe https://someurl/playlist.m3u --sout "#file{dst=C:\users\me\desktop\$rd.mp3}" --run-time=15 vlc://quit}
```

So I created a task in the Windows Task Scheduler to automate the execution.

This is the XML of the "Actions" tab:

```
<Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>powershell</Command>
      <Arguments>-noexit -command {$rd = get-date -format "yyyyMMdd"; C:\"Program Files"\VideoLan\vlc\vlc.exe https://someurl/playlist.m3u --sout "#file{dst=C:\users\me\desktop\$rd.mp3}" --run-time=15 vlc://quit}</Arguments>
    </Exec>
</Actions>
```

Now, once the task is triggered, the opened PowerShell shows this error:

```
The string is missing the terminator: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try changing out the braces `{   }` for double-quotes `"   "` and escaping all the inside double-quotes with a backslash `\"`  So I think the command should look like this  `powershell -noprofile -command "$rd = get-date -format \"yyyyMMdd\"; & \"C:\Program Files\VideoLan\vlc\vlc.exe\" https://someurl/playlist.m3u --sout \"#file{dst=C:\users\me\desktop\$rd.mp3}\" --run-time=15 vlc://quit"`  Have a look at this answer if you have 20 minutes to spare :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/31413730/11954025

Comment: Thank you! That worked: `powershell -command "$rd = get-date -format \"yyyyMMdd\"; C:\"\Program Files\"\VideoLan\vlc\vlc.exe https://someurl/playlist.m3u --sout \"#file{dst=C:\users\me\desktop\$rd.mp3}\" --run-time=15 vlc://quit"`